# struts2 redirect to another page

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am unable to redirect to another page using struts2 when i manually submit the form and not by form's action

my struts.xml part

```
<action name="login" class="com.abc.csm.actions.Login">
         <result type="plainText" name="success"></result>
    </action>
<action name="home">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/view/Welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

on index.html i have a form with 2 fields, `email` and `project id` so i submit this form like

```
$(function() {
    $("#loginSubmitBtn").click(submitLogin);

    function submitLogin()
    {
        if(validate())
        {
            $.post("/csm/login.action",
              { emailaddress:   document.getElementById("email_id").value,
                projectid:      document.getElementById("project_id").value },
                  function(xml)
                  {
                        if($(xml).find('isSuccess').text()=="true")
                        {
                            sessiontoken=$(xml).find('sessiontoken').text();
                            $.post("/csm/home.action", {
                                sessiontoken:    sessiontoken
                            });
                        }
                  }
            );
}
    }
});

});
```

In the above code i am trying to get `sessiontoken` from server side response, validate if login was a success and then redirect it to `/csm/home.action`, but i does not gets redirected, I am using fiddler to monitor, and i can see the content of Welcome.jsp (/csm/home.action is mapped to Welcome.jsp in struts.xml) in response, but no redirection happens. What is the solution here? Thanks

**Updated** this works, Also can you check the way I am attaching `sessiontoken` is it correct?

```
  $('#submitDBtn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(validate())
    {

        $.post("/csm/login.action",
          { emailaddress:   document.getElementById("email_id").value,
            projectid:      document.getElementById("project_id").value },
              function(xml)
              {
                    if($(xml).find('isSuccess').text()=="true")
                    {
                        sessiontoken=$(xml).find('sessiontoken').text();
                        /*$.post("/csm/home.action", {
                            sessiontoken:    sessiontoken
                        });*/
                        $('#launch').attr('action', '/csm/home.action?sessiontoken='+sessiontoken);
                        $('#launch').submit();
                    }
              }
        );

    }

});
```

Comment: you can not redirect you page using ajax, the last post which you have used will take you back on the same page.

Comment: @Vivek: Are you sure perfectly? Can you show me some source if you have any?

Comment: that's the concept Ajax used...if we don't want to redirect page but still want to populate data in that scenario we use `ajax`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this

upon success instead of

```
$.post("/csm/home.action", {sessiontoken:sessiontoken});
```

try

```
window.location = "/csm/home.action"+sessiontoken;
```

abt form submit

have a look here

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/disable-submit-button-on-form-submit.html

you can disable the default behaviour of form with javascript and then after some processing submit the form using jquery

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

and about whether its a good way or not it depends but i have hear and read that one should avoid it ...

**EDIT**
about sending sessiontoken in hidden field, just before submitting the form do this

```
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "sessiontoken");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", sessiontoken);
    var form = document.getElementById("yourFormId");
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    $('#formid').submit();
```

Comment: @3nigma: This i one of the reasons i switched to struts2, anything else apart from `window.location`?

Comment: @3nigma: Ok, I don't want to use form's action, coz i need to perform some operations before submit, so is there any other  way to submit form and redirect? Also is `window.location` bad way of redirecting?

Comment: @Abhishek-after validation try this-$('#formId').submit();

Comment: @3nigma: After i use form's id to bind `submit` and disable submit button, the submit button is unclicable, so nothing happens after that (referred your links)

Comment: change `type=submit` to `type=button` and on button click do something with the form and then submit the form `$('#formid').submit();`

Comment: the button is unclickable because you might be doing `$('#btnID).attr('disabled','disabled')` you need to enable it afterwards

Comment: @3nigma: Please check my code for 1 more query.. it works now. :) thanks

Comment: you are sending the sessiontoken as query string paramenter where as i thin k your form `method` is `POST`, you need to send the `sessionToken` in the hidden field

Comment: @3nigma: so i added `document.getElementById("sessiontoken").value=sessiontoken;` where sessiontoken is a hidden field inside form